# Jenkins Job DSL Plugin: How to Modify Parameters on other jobs

Tags: jenkins, plugins, parameters, configuration, dsl

I want to create a job in Jenkins which modifies an existing parameter on another job.

I'm using the Job DSL Plugin. The code I'm using is:

```
job('jobname'){
  using('jobname')
  parameters {
    choiceParam('PARAMETER1',['newValue1', 'newValue2'],'')
  }
}
```

However, this only adds another parameter with the same name in the other job.

I'm trying the alternative to delete all parameters and start from scratch, but I haven't found the way to do that using Job DSL (not even with the Configure block).

Another alternative would be to define the other job completely and start from scratch, but that would make the job too complicated, specially if I want to apply this change to many jobs at a time.

¿Is there a way to edit or delete lines on the config.xml file using the Job DSL plugin?